# How to replace/override a class within the same namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enums, overriding

Basically, I have a class defined in my website which contains a bunch of Enums to define some constant numbers. Whenever the website updates to a new version, it will (and should) use the original class definition. In some rare cases I need to overwrite the values of these Enums per website. So I was thinking I could drop a customised file into the website that redefines the original class with the "override" statement, so that the original file will always stay the same, but not get used.

HOWEVER, when I add the file it of course throws the error: 'className' already contains a definition for 'enumName'.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Example:

```
public enum PageIDs
{
    Login = 2,
    SearchResults = 3,
    DocumentsLibrary = 4,
    Error = 5,
    PageNotFound = 6,
    NewsAndEvents = 7
}
```

should be replaced by:

```
public enum PageIDs
{
    Login = 2,
    SearchResults = 3,
    DocumentsLibrary = 4,
    Error = 9,
    PageNotFound = 15,
    NewsAndEvents = 17
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example how you want to change enum values in a new version? SO just put old Enum and new one

Comment: Ok, have added it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if these values are changing you better design your application as configurable. you can use web config file or other configuration xml or DB.

Answer (score 1):

When using enums which can be seen as "constants", you don't normally change the values.

Your option is to either create a class with virtual int properties or to load some configuration file as UnhandledException mentions.

With the solution below you need to instantiate the class

```
public class BasePageIDs {
    public virtual int Login { get { return 2; } }
    public virtual int Search { get { return 3; } }
}

public class SpecializedPageIDs : BasePageIds {
    public override int Search { get { return 4; } }
}
```

If you would like static getters you won't be able to create an inheritance, but should rather load your ints from somewhere else, either from configuration of from the above classes for instance.

```
public static class PageIDs {
    public static int Login { get { /* load from configuration */ return config; } }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks for this, I think I will have to save these settings in a configuration DB table. I didn't initially, because the values do not change once it has been deployed (on a per-website-value). Thanks for the help. Since UnhandledException suggested it first, I will mark his as the answer, but your comments were also helpful.